# Use NSNotificationCenter to hide the keyboard visible for UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsnotificationcenter

I am having a `UITextView` and a custom button in navigation bar. My custom button shows a sliding menu when pressed and the view at front is shifted slightly to right.

The problem is that if I tap on custom button, still my keyboard is visible. Yet the view having text view is shifted to right. I searched many solutions and got many that can hide keyboard if I tap on navigation bar. But no solution for tapping on my custom button.

A friend gave me idea that this can be achieved by `NSNotificationCenter`. But how, I dont know. 
How I can achieve it by using `NSNotifiactionCenter`

**EDIT:**

I am using and external library to create the custom button.

Answer (score 0):

From the button's action you can call `[self.myTextView resignFirstResponder]`

**EDIT:**

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
    [self.myTextView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work if I press on custom button. Can you share an example to hide keyboard by pressing custom button?

Comment: See the edit. Don't forget to connect the button to the `IBAction` in the Interface Builder

Comment: How can i connect the custom button created programatically with Interface Builder?

Comment: If you created the button programmatically, then you don't have to connect it with the Interface Builder. I modified my answer